# angular dependency injection - ignore when not provided - use case: MAT_DIALOG_DATA

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, mat-dialog

some of my components. have 2 way initial parameters via constructor.

1. routes parameters, for using via url.
2. matDialogData, used when comopnent opens in a dialog.

like this:

```
constructor(private dialog: MatDialog,
private route:ActivatedRoute,
@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) private data)
```

the option of matDialog work fine, but route option (was work fine before adding of matDialogData) fail with:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[InjectionToken MatDialogData -> InjectionToken MatDialogData -> InjectionToken MatDialogData]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken MatDialogData!
NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(AppModule)[InjectionToken MatDialogData -> InjectionToken MatDialogData -> InjectionToken MatDialogData]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for InjectionToken MatDialogData!
```

is there a way to config this parameter `@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) private data` as nullable/optional, and ignore from this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the [`@Optional()`](https://angular.io/api/core/Optional) decorator like this:

```js
class SomeClass {
  constructor(
    private dialog: MatDialog,
    private route:ActivatedRoute,
    @Optional() @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) private data
  ) {}
}
```